# Получение данных из формы в сервлетном фильтре

Tags: java, servlet

Есть простая форма для входа:

```
<form action="/showallusers" method="get">
    Login: <input type="text" name="login"/>
    Password: <input type="password" name="password"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Войти">
</form>
```

Как получить данные этой формы в сервлетном фильтре? Делаю

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    String name = (String)request.getAttribute("login");
    response.getWriter().println(name);
}
```

Но в `name` всегда `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для получения таких значений из запроса нужно использовать метод [getParameter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter(java.lang.String)):

```
String name = request.getParameter("login");
```

Атрибуты, получаемые с помощью метода [getAttribute](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getAttribute(java.lang.String)), - это другое.

Comment: Большое спасибо

Comment: @Роман на здоровье. Если ответ вас устраивает, не забудьте отметить его как правильный (галочка слева от ответа).